# Adding arrows to the Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have generated a plot of 16 points. and I have joined them using plot in Matlab. This is the function that I am using currently.

```
plot(X1,Y1,'--rs','LineWidth',2,...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                'MarkerFaceColor','g',...
                'MarkerSize',10);
```

The plot generated is this
[image]

The problem is that I donot know which point was plotted first and then which point was plotted second and so on. The red line joining them is so haphazard that it is impossible to follow it. Is is possible to plot the direction of the red dotted lines shown in the image ?

Comment: I suggest to put a label with a number above each marker instead of drawing the direction of jointing line.

Comment: and how can I do this in Matlab. This link on linespec properties donot specify the marker label or some other property like this http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve a sense of direction by varying the color for each segment:

```
N = length(X1);
cmap = flipud(hot(N-1)); % or try other colormaps instead of "hot"
plot(X1,Y1,'s','MarkerEdgeColor','k','MarkerFaceColor','g','MarkerSize',10);
hold on
for ii = 1:N-1
  plot([X1(ii) X1(ii+1)], [Y1(ii) Y1(ii+1)],'LineWidth',2,'Color',cmap(ii,:))
end
```

[image]

You should experiment with the definition of the variable `cmap` to obtain some colors you like. For example, if you don't want too light yellow you can use

```
cmap = flipud(hot(2*N-1));
cmap = cmap(N+1:end,:);
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Actually it wouldn't be too hard to add two lines in the for loop that will make the arrow head.